# Java ME 3.0 SDK on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, java-me

Is it possible to develop java me applications on linux? It appears that there is no linux version of the sdk. Otherwise what would you suggest as a good language to develop mobile applications?

Answer (score 5):

Use the 2.5.2 SDK.  It works pretty well under Linux, actually.

I'd also second the recommendation for Android, where Linux is definitely not a second-class citizen.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install (an earlier version of) the SDK on a Windows machine and then copy the relevant libraries to my Linux development environment.  I wish sun would provide the all the JDKs in zip/tar format.  I hate having to INSTALL software just to get .jar files out of an archive.  I should note that the SDK includes a mobile device emulator that doesn't work under Linux but you just need the .jars to compile code.

Answer (score 1):

The Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 runs under Unbuntu 6.x, more details here:
http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download.html

We use WinXP for J2ME and Ubuntu for Android. Though that's more down to the preference of the coders than any limitiations.

Answer (score 0):

> Otherwise what would you suggest as a
>   good language to develop mobile
>   applications?

Well, you can still use the Java lang.
But maybe develop some Android apps.

Answer (score 0):

virtual box can be a great help here, for OSX and Linux users, unfortunately most of the emulators and sdks, in particular the preverifiers are geared for Windows first, a prime example being Blackberry

Our flow tends to be to develop the bulk of the application in the std wtk environment, then do the final porting and tweaking under a virtualised Windows environment